# How to call an automation script from an automation script in Maximo

Tags: maximo

Could anyone tell me how to invoke an action automation script from an automation script in Maximo. I have achieved this before but can't remember/find the procedure used to call an action script.

Answer (score 4):

When invoking another script, it doesn't matter if it is an action script or a script just sitting out there with no launch points (or even one already triggering on its own otherwise with, say, an object save launch point). The below code assumes Jython and Maximo of at least 7.6.0.x (I forget exactly what version added this feature).

First, you do need to make sure you import java.util.HashMap into your script. Then, you start by creating a new HashMap. This is the script context that you will *put* all of your implicit variables into for the other script. You then use the "invokeScript" method of the implicit *service* or script context (if this is in an integration script) object. The first parameter of that method is the name of the new script you want to invoke and the second parameter is your HashMap that is the context for the new script.

```
from java.util import HashMap

subScriptCtx = HashMap()
subScriptCtx.put("mbo", woMbo)
subScriptCtx.put("var1", someObject)
subScriptCtx.put("var2", MXServer.getMXServer().getDate())
...
service.invokeScript("OTHERSCRIPTNAME", subScriptCtx)
```

Comment: After the `service.invokeScript()` call, whatever variables were defined with script-level scope will be available for you to call `subScriptCtx.get("outvar")` to get the value of.

Comment: It is helpful to think of the different launch points executing code like @Dex's to call your script. Further, it is helpful to recognize that such code would not be executed to call your script if you just use the Execute button in Automation Scripts, hence why the feature was taken away when so many people raised support tickets of `mbo` not being defined when they used Execute.